# dask: Increasing speed of mutliple file loading into single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dask

I am merging several thousands of reasonably sized (~1 million rows) dataframes together on a fairly regular basis.
While I can get pandas to work with `read_csv`, it is a terrible solution due to the extremely large overhead.

I need a faster solution to this and dask apparently has this multiple csv functionality baked into their `read_csv`/`read_table` functions.

However, I haven't noticed much improvement in speed with these solutions.

Is there a way to increase the speed of the following type of process? :

```
import io
import re
import numpy as np
import dask.bag as dbag
import dask.dataframe as ddf

def filter_data(fp, ix_col = 'index_here', val_col = 'some_value'):
    dask_frame = ddf.read_table(fp)
    # filter to only one column and index (like a series)
    series = dask_frame[[ix_col, val_col]].set_index(ix_col)

    # Rename it to be the filename / file_id
    file_id = re.match("file_(.+)\.txt", fp)[1]
    series.columns = [file_id]
    return series

def get_dataframe(file_paths):
    # Make a collection
    dasks_bag = dbag.from_sequence(file_paths)

    # Open the files as dask frame and filter each to series-like frames
    filtered_dfs = dasks_bag.map(filter_data)

    # Compute pandas dataframe on each within the list
    filtered_dfs = filtered_dfs.compute()

    # concatenate them together
    df = ddf.concat(filtered_dfs, axis = 1)

    # Compute on concatenated again, so it becomes pandas dataframe
    return df.dropna(how = "all").compute()



# Just write some random files here
paths = ['file_120202021.txt', 'file_123.txt', 'file_12330.txt']
for fp in paths:
    with open(fp, 'w') as f:
        f.write('index_here\tsome_value\tother_cols\n')
        for row in range(0,1000):
            for val, other_col in np.random.rand(1, 2):
                f.write(str(row)+'\t'+str(val)+'\t'+str(other_col)+'\n')

# Make a dataframe with dask
get_dataframe(paths)
```

**Edit:**
I have a small script here that shows the failure of dask:
The time required for dask on my machine is **1.87 seconds**
while the time required for pandas is **0.29 seconds**

Clearly, I am doing this wrong, as dask was specifically made for more rapid computation on dataframes.

```
import io
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.bag as dbag
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import time

def get_dask_dataframe(file_paths,  ix_col = 'index_here', val_col = 'some_value'):
    # Make a collection
    dasks_bag = dbag.from_sequence(file_paths)

    # read and filter to data of interest
    dask_frames = ddf.read_table(file_paths, include_path_column = True)[[ix_col, val_col, 'path']]

    # Make pandas dataframe
    df = dask_frames.compute()

    # Pivot since read_table puts path in one column
    df = df.pivot_table(values = val_col, index = ix_col, columns = 'path')
    return df.dropna(how = "all")

def get_pandas_dataframe(file_paths, ix_col = 'index_here', val_col = 'some_value'):
    # Make a collection
    l = []
    for f in file_paths:
        series = pd.read_csv(f, sep = '\t')[[ix_col, val_col]].set_index(ix_col)
        # Rename it to be the filename / file_id
        file_id = re.match("file_(.+)\.txt", f)[1]
        series.columns = [file_id]
        l += [series]

    # concatenate them together
    df = pd.concat(l, axis = 1)
    return df.dropna(how = "all")


# Just write a whole bunch of random files
paths = ['file_'+str(i)+'.txt' for i in range(0, 100)]
for fp in paths:
    with open(fp, 'w') as f:
        f.write('index_here\tsome_value\tother_cols\n')
        for row in range(0,1000):
            for val, other_col in np.random.rand(1, 2):
                f.write(str(row)+'\t'+str(val)+'\t'+str(other_col)+'\n')

t0 = time.time()
# Make a dataframe with dask
df1 = get_dask_dataframe(paths)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)

t0 = time.time()
# Make a dataframe with dask
df2 = get_pandas_dataframe(paths)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```